# Is the higher-order component in React a closure?

Tags: reactjs

React has a [higher-order component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

Concretely, a higher-order component is a function that takes a component and returns a new component.

Is the higher-order component a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) or not?

If yes or no, why?

Answer (score 0):

A function that returns a function can be considered to be a closure if the first function has an argument, because the returned function persistently "closes" over the value contained in that argument.

```
const higherOrderFn = (arg1) => {
  return (arg2) => arg1 + arg2;
};
const add3 = higherOrderFn(3);
```

Here, the function contained in `add3` closes over the parameter passed to the higher-order function, 3.

In React, a higher-order component is doing the same sort of thing. A component is a function. A function that returns a component is a higher-order function. If the initial function call is passed a value that's used inside the returned function/component, then there's a closure there.